# Add new menu areas in child theme

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a child theme (from Sydney theme) the question is how can i add a new menu area and define its location in template using only functions.php file? I don't want modify or duplicate parent theme files 'cause if i update parent theme all change will be lost.

For register menu i have this:

```
register_nav_menus( array(
    'top' => __( 'Top Menu', 'adn' ),
    'social' => __( 'Social Links Menu', 'adn' ),
    'footer' => __( 'Footer Menu', 'adn' )
) );
```

So the question is how can define its position without modify header.php or footer.php file?

Comment: You can register multiple sidebar, navigation bar. You need to get them according to logic get_sidebar(my_sidebar) with if-else or switch for certain conditions.

Comment: Hi, but how i must define in functions.php if i want to put that menus in a specific places of my template? (header, footer, sidebar, etc)

Answer (score 0):

To place the new nav menus, you'll need to edit the header/footer/sidebar template files, but you can safely do that in the child theme.

To recap here are the steps:

1. First register the new menu in your child theme's `functions.php` file:

```
function register_new_menus() {
  register_nav_menu( array(
    'top' => __( 'Top Menu', 'adn' ),
    'social' => __( 'Social Links Menu', 'adn' ),
    'footer' => __( 'Footer Menu', 'adn' )
  ) );
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_new_menus' );
```

2. Add the new menu to a location in your theme's template files (header, footer, sidebar, etc.):

```
wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'top' ) );
```

You can copy the specific template files to the child theme directory and edit them there.